# Replacing specific values in data frame with a new data frame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

This is the original data frame:

```
> df = data.frame(name=c('a', 'b', 'c'), age = c(12, 23, 34), sex = c('boy', 'girl', 'boy'))
> df
  name age  sex
1    a  12  boy
2    b  23 girl
3    c  34  boy
```

And this data frame contains the values I need to modify:

```
> newdf = data.frame(name=c('a', 'c'), sex=c('girl', 'girl'))
> newdf
  name  sex
1    a girl
2    c girl
```

I need to replace values in `df` with values in `newdf`.

The expected results should be:

```
> expectedResult = data.frame(name=c('a', 'b', 'c'), age=c(12, 23, 34), sex=c('girl', 'girl', 'girl'))
> expectedResult
  name age  sex
1    a  12 girl
2    b  23 girl
3    c  34 girl
```

I tried using `set` or `cbind` but didn't work.
Any idea?

`dplyr` or `data.table` solutions are welcomed. Need a solution that works for data frame with >100 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can join `on` 'name' and assign 'i.sex' values to 'sex'.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[newdf, sex:= i.sex , on = 'name']
 df
 #     name age  sex
 #1:    a  12 girl
 #2:    b  23 girl
 #3:    c  34 girl
```

---

If there are multiple columns, for example by changing the 'newdf'

```
 newdf = data.frame(name=c('a', 'c'), age = c(14, 22), sex=c('girl', 'girl'))
```

Create a vector of columns to change ('nm1'), join `on` 'name', use `mget` to get the `i.` columns in a `list` and assign the output to "nm1".

```
 nm1 <- c("sex", "age")
 setDT(df)[newdf, (nm1) := mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), on = 'name']
 df
 #   name age  sex
 #1:    a  14 girl
 #2:    b  23 girl
 #3:    c  22 girl
```

Comment: What if I have multiple columns? I tried a loop for i.col but didn't work.

Comment: @shawni Then use `c('sex', 'something') := list(i.sex, i.something)`

Comment: how can I make it dynamic, like `i.col` ? It has to be a solution that works for data frame with >100 columns.

Comment: @shawnl  Yes, but you showed an example with a single column

Comment: so you're right and i'm right. I'll repost this question.

Comment: @shawni I posted an option, but it is not tested without a reproducible example

Comment: You're awesome! I didn't know about `mget`. Thanks!

Comment: @shawnl Glad to help you.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which you can use for all these kind of replacements between all different kinds of dataframes

```
replace_frame_with <- function(dataframe1,dataframe2,vec){

 myvector <- colnames(out)
 yourvector <- colnames(out2)
 out <- dataframe1[vec,]
 out2 <- dataframe2[vec,]

 if(ncols(out)>ncols(out2)){
  cols_to_exchange <- myvector[myvector==yourvector]
  out[,cols_to_exchange] <- out2[,cols_to_exchange]
  return(out)
 }

 if(ncols(out2)>ncols(out)){
  cols_to_exchange <- yourvector[yourvector==myvector]
  out[,cols_to_exchange] <- out2[,cols_to_exchange]
  return(out)
 }

}
```

Function args are as follows:

dataframe1= the data frame that you want to replace values of

dataframe2= the data frame that you want to use the values in replacing the value of the first argument

vec= the rows that you wan't to replace.

Read through the code, I might have some mistakes here but the main logic is true. You can apply this logic in your own function if my function has some mechanical mistakes, I believe I would help you at least in that manner.

As you can see the function will adjust to the columns and rows automically, requiring no effort from you.

Remember to use the as.NA is.Na and other NA fxns to fill in the rows of the NA of the one with shorter, row that's how you can adjust the rows with built-in functions in the R programming software, you can implement this function into the function code above, That's all your choice it's up to you.

```
  replace_frame_with(df,newdf,c(1,3))
```